# Magento Newsletter submit does not show in left column

Tags: magento, newsletter, subscribe

I am new to Magento and would appreciate some help.

I struggled to add the newsletter widget to my left column.

I was able to do so by :
1) Going to CMS-->Widget and creating a new Widget, with the type as CMS Static Block, my title i set as Newsletter. I set to display on all pages, and the block reference i set to Left Column.
2) I then went to CMS-->Static Blocks, created a new block called newsletter and updated the content with:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

However if I do this, then the block does not show up, if I change it to

```
 {{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

the widget show, but does not update update subscription, I understand from other posts that this will not work.

What do I need to do tho get the newsletter/subscribe working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to enable the module under System--->Advanced--->Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

in app/design/frontend/theme/theme/layout/newsletter.xml:

Change from :

```
<reference name="footer">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" as="newsletter" before="footer_store_language" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

To

```
<reference name="left">
 <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" before="-" />
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply anjali, it is already like your suggested code.